# Loop through column, search for text, get value of X

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a CommandButton macro in excel to determine if the name is the same with the one I'm searching for and if it is the same I will be getting the value of the cell beside it and add it all together to get the final amount.

[This will be the example that I would like to do:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpCqY.png)

this will be the flow:
I will first check if the cell value is the same with the name
If it is James I will get the amount and add it to the total value for James, same goes for Ramirez
After everything is checked the accumulated value will then be placed on the cell beside James/Ramirez's name

Is there a way to do this in Excel? or any faster way to do this without using a commandbutton?

Comment: i'm currently new to this function and wasn't successful all I got that was correct is only the skeleton of the code:

Comment: Then provide us with the code?

Comment: i'm currently new to this function and wasn't successful all I got that was correct is only the skeleton of the code:

Dim i As Integer. j As Integer, K As Integer

For i = 3 to 2000
    If Cell(i,1) = "James" then j = j + Cell(i, 2)
    Else k = k + Cell(i,2)
    End If

Range("D5") = j
Range("D6") = k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use marco for this.

You can simply type in a function

In the example shown below,

```
E2:=SUMIF(A2:A6,D2,B2:B6)
E3:=SUMIF(A2:A6,D3,B2:B6)
```

EXPLANATION

```
=SUMIF(range_where_the_keyword_will_be,term_to_search,corresponding_values)
```

If you type "Ramirez" in D2, E2 will give you "300".

[image]

**TIPS**

If you want it to give you a message (such as, "not existing"), when you type in a name that is not in the list, you can try the function below.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A6,D2)<>0,SUMIF(A2:A6,D2,B2:B6),"Not existing")
```